# User input to break infinite loop?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm working on calculating a bunch of triangles with special properties for a Number Theorist friend. There are infinitely many of these triangles, but they require a lot of computational power to find.

We've got an infinite loop running through different b,d combinations. When the program ends, it calls the go(dict) function to export the triangles it found. Currently, we tell the program at the start what interval of time to run for. This is causing problems when we realize we need the computing power for something else, but the program still has hours to run and we don't want to lose the triangles it has already calculated by exiting the program without running go(dict).

Ideally, we want some user input to cause the program to break the loop, run go(dict) with whatever current version of the dictionary it is holding in memory, then exit. Trying with atexit.register(go, dict) was unsuccessful, as it is called many times within the loop and runs many times when the program is terminated.

(See the abbreviated loop code below)

```
interval = eval(input("How many hours shall I run for? "))*3600
starttime = time.time()
dict = {}
b = start_value
while True:
    for d in range (1, b):
        compute stuff

        if (condition):
            add triangle to dict

    if (time.time()-starttime)>interval:
        go(dict)
        return
    b +=1
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what exceptions <strike>are</strike> can be used for: you press Ctrl+C to interrupt the process, and your code handles it by saving the results:

```
while True:
    try:
        # your code here
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        go(dict)
        break
```

Note that you can't `return` from a standalone loop, but you can `break` from it, however.

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer. You are correct about the break, but we're searching for a unicorn among the special triangles, so the return is for the function that holds the loop (essentially giving up the search), since there is code that follows the loop to only be executed once the unicorn triangle we're searching for is found.

Answer (score 1):

one thing you can do is take over ctrl+c using `except KeyboardInterrupt:` when you send an interrupt to the script it will run this block in which you can put code to exit cleanly
here is an example:

```
i = 0
try:
    while True:
        i+=1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'caught INT'
    print i
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Signals:

```
import signal
interrupted = False # Used to break the loop when we send SIGINT

# When SIGINT is received, set interrupted to True
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global interrupted
    interrupted = True

# Sets signal_handler to run if a SIGINT was received
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

interval = eval(input("How many hours shall I run for? "))*3600
starttime = time.time()
dict = {}
b = start_value
while True:
    for d in range (1, b):
        compute stuff

        if (condition):
            add triangle to dict

        if (time.time()-starttime)>interval:
            go(dict)
            break

        if interrupted:
            go(dict)
            break
    b +=1
```

Now when we hit `ctrl+c`, we set `interrupted` to `True` which runs `go(dict)` and breaks the loop.

Comment: Good reference for people that come here in future!